# C# MySQL Parameterized update returning nothing

Tags: c#, mysql, parameters

Whenever I try to update my database, the result ends up being 0.

If I do it in HeidiSQL, it updates just fine, so I know it's not the query.

I have my suspicion that it has to do with the parameters, but I'm unsure regarding that.

I tried with both @ and ?, but neither have worked.

```
MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE `users` SET `cash`=@Cash, 
                           `distance_driven`=@DistanceDriven, `jobs_done`=@JobsDone,
                           `job_rank`=@JobRank WHERE `username`='@Username';"
                       , Connection);

Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cash", Cash);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DistanceDriven", DistanceDriven);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobsDone", JobsDone);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobRank", JobRank);
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", UName);

int result = Command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // result should be 1

Console.WriteLine(result); // ends up being 0
```

The connection opens fine, but I have no idea why it won't execute the query with the parameters.

Here is the function that requires this update:

```
public void UpdateUserInfo(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs evt, string uUName)
{
    bool cont = false;

    Console.WriteLine("UUI 1: " + evt.SignalTime); // gets here fine

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UUI 2: " + evt.SignalTime); // gets here fine
        Database database = new Database();
        database.Connect();



        if (database.UpdateUserData(uUName, TotalCashWallet, TotalDistanceDriven, JobsDone, JobRank))
        {
            cont = true;
            Console.WriteLine("UUI 3: " + evt.SignalTime); // doesn't get here
        }

        if (cont == true)
        {
            cont = false;

            Console.WriteLine("UUI 4: " + evt.SignalTime);

            if (database.UpdateUserBank(uUName, BankInfo.Money, BankInfo.BonusPercentage, BankInfo.BonusLevel))
            {
                UserInfoUpdated = true;
                Console.WriteLine("UUI 5: " + evt.SignalTime);
                UserInfoUpdatedTimer.Enabled = true;
                return;
            }

        }

        UserInfoUpdated = false;
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UUI 6: " + evt.SignalTime);
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        ErrorHandler.WriteToLog(e.StackTrace);
        ErrorHandler.WriteToLog(e.Message);
        ErrorHandler.WriteToLog("------------------------------");
    }

    return;

}
```

It doesn't get to the catch part, so it won't log anything.
I tried with both Exception and MysqlException, but it doesn't catch an error.

Doing it the unsafe way works

```
MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand("
    UPDATE `users`
        SET `cash`=" + Cash + ",
            `distance_driven`=" + DistanceDriven + ",
            `jobs_done`=" + JobsDone + ",
            `job_rank`=" + JobRank + "
    WHERE `username`='" + UName + "';"
, Connection);
```

Comment: does a record exist with the username in you request?

Comment: yes, it updates fine in HeidiSQL, as stated in the second paragraph.

Comment: When you set a parameter's value using `AddWithValue`, you don't need the `@`. You also shouldn't be quoting `@UserName` in your `where` clause...

Comment: I tried without that as well, but it still would end up updating 0 rows.

Comment: `where username='@Username'` should be`where username=@Username` - no apostrophes. Currently you're looking for a username which starts with an @ etc.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity and eliminating the obvious, you are executing this query aren't you?

Comment: Jezza, no offense, but I think you have a bit of trouble reading...
int result = Command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // result should be 1

Comment: What are your parameter's types? I mean, "Cash", "JobRank", "UName" etc. Are they all string?

Comment: decimal Cash, int DistanceDriven, int JobsDone, int JobRank, string UName  


In the database it's decimal(10,2) cash, int(10) distance_driven, int(10) jobs_done, int(10) job_rank, and varchar(32) username

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the single quotes around string parameters. Use this query instead:

```
string query = @"
    UPDATE `users` SET
        `cash`=@Cash,
        `distance_driven`=@DistanceDriven,
        `jobs_done`=@JobsDone,
        `job_rank`=@JobRank
    WHERE
        `username`=@Username"

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, Connection);
```

Comment: That was my initial query, but that didn't do anything, and I can't do that since some usernames contain spaces in them.

Comment: @Kibo this is a prepared statement. Parameters are actually sent separately from the query. You don't need to worry about spaces.

Comment: @Kibo please try with the exact query I provided and check if the data has been changed in the database.

Comment: Tried it, but still no change in the database.

Comment: In that case, you need to find the minimal code that reproduces the problem. Right now there are too many things that could go wrong. Try with a new table and just one field, without a `WHERE` condition first. See if that would work.

Comment: Tried that, returns with that the column in question can't be null.
I think the parameters aren't being replaced for some reason, and I tried with all kinds of variations, @ and ? in the query, @, ? and no prefix in the parameters.

Comment: I tried that as well, it still wouldn't set the parameters right.

Comment: @Kibo what are the exact values of the parameters you are passing to the query?

Comment: Differs per player, but I know that it should work as intended because I'm testing it on myself, and my data is in the database. It's weird because concatenating the values directly into the query (unsafe, I know) works fine, but using parameters it decides to just flip.

Comment: @Kibo are there any culture-specific characters in your name?

Comment: No, they're all UTF-8.